# Run OS commands Conditionally(shell/plink)

Tags: shell, plink

Looking for a way to accomplish some requirement.
I am issue 2 commands in remote server by using plink and need to get information.

## Requirement

If $CHECKVALUE returns any value, I just need to issue 'uname' command.
If $CHECKVALUE doesn't return any value, I need to issue 'ls' & 'uname' commands.

```
plink -ssh -l user01 -pw user01 192.168.0.5 " . .bash_profile 2> Nil; echo $CHECKVALUE; ls; uname; "
```

Can you let me know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$CHECKVALUE` is coming from the environment on the remote system and not the system issuing the plink command, you just need to do this:

```
plink -ssh -l user01 -pw user01 192.168.0.5 ' . .bash_profile 2> /dev/null; if [ -n "$CHECKVALUE" ] echo "$CHECKVALUE"; else ls; fi; uname; '
```

Note that I changed `Nil` to `/dev/null` as this appears to be a UNIX-like system. If this is going to Cygwin maybe `Nil` works too; I've never tried it. I also converted to using single quotes instead of double, as the double quotes would cause `$CHECKVALUE` to be substituted before the remote call is made.

Comment: Even though there is CHECKVALUE env variable in remote side, the command only prints the result of 'uname'. If there is CHECKVALUE variable, I should print $CHECKVALUE env variable value and the result of 'uname' without 'ls' result. Can you check it again? Thank you.

Comment: When I use a single quotation, I got "The system cannot find the path specified." error. Strangely, all of commands works in linux itself work well but when I use plink, [echo "$CHECKVALUE"] part doesn't work and only print blank line. Let met test it more. Thank you.

Comment: Correction: [else ls] part doesn't work instead. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: I modified it like: ......... /dev/null; env | grep CHECKVALUE && uname || ls; uname; "      It works anyway. ^.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Workaround: ....../dev/null; env | grep CHECKVALUE && echo 'Found' || ls; uname;   It really works now.